# I can´t see returned image - PhoneGap

Tags: android, image, cordova, camera

Where I make mistakes? I would like to see image after save button click. I see only white screen without returned image. I am using Android and Galaxy S device.

```
$(function(){       

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", phonegapLoaded, false);

    function phonegapLoaded(){

    }

    $("#vyfotit").click(function(){

            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, {quality: 70, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});                       

        });

    function onSuccess(imageURI){

        var image = document.getElementById("image");

        image.src = imageURI;

        image.style.display = block;

        }

    function onError(message){

        navigator.notification.alert("Failed because: " + message);

    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include permissions for accessing the camera in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I use this permission. This permission is included in manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: Are you using the default Camera app or a custom one? Which function is called: onSuccess or onError?

Comment: I am using default camera app. Neither of function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an element with the id image? Only reason I could see this not working is that the element doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: Yep, image element has id="image"

Comment: hmm looks like your functions are called outside of the phonegap ready function which could also lead to some issues try attaching the click listener inside of that vs outside..